Number of pairs of vectors with sum zero everywhere except for one entry is less than $m+n-1$
I saw this problem online: I have $m$ vectors $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_m$ and another $n$ vectors $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n$. All of the $m+n$ vectors are of form
$$
[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N]
$$
where all $x_i$'s are integers and $N$ is some positive integer. Let $K$ be the number of indices $k$ such that there exists a pair $(i,j)$, where $i = 1, 2, \ldots n$ and $j = 1, 2, \ldots, m$, for which $a_i + b_j = e_k$. I want to prove that $K< m+n$.
I saw the following solution: The set
$$
\left\{ \sum_i x_i a_i + \sum_j y_j b_j \mid x_i, y_j \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{ and } \sum_{i} x_i = \sum_{j} y_j \right\}
$$
has dimension at most $m+n-1$ so $K < m+n$.
I couldn't understand why the set has dimension at most $m+n-1$ and why the dimension of the set tells us anything about $K$. I also wonder if there is any way to prove that $K< m+n$.

in fact it is false... just take all vectors equal to the same vector $[1,0,\dots,0]$

The solution makes sense only if $K$ is the number of indices $k$ for which there exists a couple $(i,j)$ with $a_i+b_j$ being a multiple of $e_k$

You are totally right! I have edited the problem.

@Exodd Can you please explain why the solution makes sense?

Let
$$
V:=\left\{ \sum_i x_i a_i + \sum_j y_j b_j \mid x_i, y_j \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{ and } \sum_{i} x_i = \sum_{j} y_j \right\}
$$
and let $I:=\lbrace k_1,\dots,k_K\rbrace$ be the $K$ (distinct) indices. Then the linear map $f\colon \mathbb R^K\hookrightarrow V$ uniquely defined by $f(e_j)=e_{k_j}\in V$ is an injection. Therefore
$$
K=\dim(\mathbb R^K)\leq \dim(V).
$$
It is clear that $\dim(V)\leq n+m$. The (non-trivial linear) condition $\sum_{i}x_i=\sum_jy_j$ removes at least one dimension from $V$, so that $\dim(V)\leq n+m-1$.

We assume that $m,n\ge 1$. As I understood, $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_m,\in\mathbb R^N$. Let
$$X=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i a_i + \sum_{j=1}^n y_j b_j : x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m\in\mathbb R, \,  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{j=1}^m y_j \right\}$$
It is easy to check that $X$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^N$. Let
$$X_0=\{b_1+a_1,b_1+a_2\ldots,b_1+a_n,b_2+a_1,b_3+a_1,\ldots,b_m+a_1\}$$
and $X'$ be the linear subspace of $X$ spanned by the set $X_0$. Then the dimension of $X'$ is at most $|X_0|=m+n-1$. Since $X_0\subset X$, and $X'$ and $X$ are linear subspaces, $X'\subset X$. On the other hand, $X\subset X'$. Indeed, let $x\in X$ be any vector. There exist $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m\in\mathbb R$ such that $$x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i a_i + \sum_{j=1}^m y_j b_j\mbox{ and }\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{j=1}^m y_j.$$ Denote the latter value by $S$. Then
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i (a_i+b_1) -\sum_{i=1}^n x_i a_1 + \sum_{j=1}^m y_j (a_1+b_j)-\sum_{j=1}^m y_j a_1=$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i (a_i+b_1)+\sum_{j=1}^m y_j (a_1+b_j)-S(a_1+b_1)\in X'.$$
So $X=X'$ and therefore the dimension $K$ of $X$ is at most $m+n-1$.
As I understood, for each natural $k\le K$, $e_k$ is the usual basis vector of $\mathbb R^N$. Let $Y_0$ be the set of vectors $e_k$ such that there exists a pair $(i,j)$, where $i\in\{1, 2, \ldots n\}$ and $j\in\{ 1, 2, \ldots, m\}$, for which $a_i + b_j = e_k$ and $Y$ be the span of the set $Y_0$. Since $Y_0\subset X$, we have $Y\subset X$, so the dimension $|Y_0|$ of $Y$ is at most the dimension of $X$, which is $K\le m+n-1$.
